# Mobile menu toggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this Responsive Navigation originally on CodePen
https://codepen.io/MarcRay/pen/vmJBn

I wanted to play around with it on a website. I've never tried to link JavaScript before. Which I believe might be my problem.

I made index.html, style.css, and javascript.js files and copied the codes into it exactly as they show. Originally the navigation wasn't showing up at all. I had it listed as such in my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Hello World</title>
<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
```

After searching I ended up adding:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" 
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

So it became:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Hello World</title>
<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" 
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
```

After I added this I was able to get the nav to display and function properly when I scrolled on desktop. Could have just been a coincidence.

My dilemma now is that when the mobile nav pops up and I click on the hamburger icon it doesn't drop down.

Here it functions as it should on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/636545/

I ran the console and no errors showed. Am I not linking the JavaScript/jQuery files correctly? Perhaps the JavaScript code is invalid? It works fine on CodePen and JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are using 2 versions of jquery , remove `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` from your head tag. if not work then keep version jquery-1.9.1.js and remove version jquery-3.3.1.min.js.